# Javascript Object variable references to strings on the console/page

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, logging, console

Ok so i have this code.

```
var Objectmary={firstName:"mary",lastName:"marshall"};
var Objectjoseph={firstName:"joseph",lastName:"marshall"};
var Objectguy={firstName:"guy", lastName:"steele"};
var contacts=[Objectmary,Objectjoseph,Objectguy];
```

Basically i want the array contacts to be printed out to either the console, or the page. However if i use

```
console.log(contacts)
```

it does not print out the array as [mary,joseph,guy], instead it gives me the object keys and values beside the position in the array.

I just want to print out Objectmary,Objectjoseph,Objectguy to the console or on the page.

Comment: Variable names have no deeper meaning, and are not accessible to the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate objects, `console.log()` objects `firstName` property; use `Array.prototype.map()` to return array containing only `firstName` properties of objects

```js
var Objectmary = {
  firstName: "mary",
  lastName: "marshall"
};
var Objectjoseph = {
  firstName: "joseph",
  lastName: "marshall"
};
var Objectguy = {
  firstName: "guy",
  lastName: "steele"
};
var contacts = [Objectmary, Objectjoseph, Objectguy];

contacts.forEach(function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.firstName, obj.lastName);
  document.body.innerHTML += obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName + "<br>"
});

var names = contacts.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.firstName
});

console.log(names);
```

Comment: When i run this code on js.do it returns JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null on line 18.

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML` was used to demonstrate approach at stacksnippets

Answer (score 0):

```
var Objectmary   = { firstName: 'mary', lastName: 'marshall' },
    Objectjoseph = { firstName: 'joseph', lastName: 'marshall' },
    Objectguy    = { firstName: 'guy', lastName: 'steele' },
    contacts     = [Objectmary, Objectjoseph, Objectguy],
    array_string = '[';

for (var i = 0, l = contacts.length; i < l; i++) {
    array_string += contacts[i].firstName;
    if (i < (l - 1)) array_string += ', '; 
}
array_string += ']';
console.log(array_string);
```